# Añadir valor de input a un array en React onChange

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, ionic

Estoy creando una herramienta tipo cotizador y shopping cart que dibuja una tabla con lo que se va agregando utilizando un `contexto` de Shopping Cart y este arreglo se exporta a un Excel usando `ExcelJS` y todo anda perfecto en la exportación del Excel, pero debo agregar un campo de Descuento a la hoja de cálculo que viene de un `input` que el usuario puede modificar desde el carrito de compras. Mi problema es que no sé cómo agregar ese valor del input al arreglo del Excel en el `onChange` del input. La tabla del carrito se dibuja de esta manera:

```
const cartItemsRutas =()=>{
    return (
        <div>
        <MostrarInformacionDeRutaSeparado />
        <IonRow style={{textAlign:"center"}} >
            {ItemsRutas && ItemsRutas.map((prod)=>(
            <IonCard style={{width:"100%",textAlign:"center"}} key={"rutas_"+String(RutasNum++)}>  
                <IonRow>
                    <IonCol size="12" size-Xs="10" sizeMd="10" sizeLg="1" sizeXl="2" style={{textAlign:"center"}}>
                        <h2>{prod.nombre}</h2>
                    </IonCol>
                    <IonCol size="12" size-Xs="10" sizeMd="10" sizeLg="1" sizeXl="1" style={{textAlign:"center"}}>
                        <InputText
                        type="number"
                        value={prod.cantidad}
                        required={true}
                        onChange={e=>{
                            prod.cantidad=e.target["value"];
                            setCantR(e.target["value"]);
                            UpdateCantidaditemsRutas2(e);
                        }
                        }
                        style={{width: "80%", border:"0px"}}
                        >
                        </InputText>
                    </IonCol>
                    <IonCol size="12" size-Xs="10" sizeMd="10" sizeLg="2" sizeXl="2" style={{textAlign:"center"}}>
                        <InputText
                            type="date"
                            value={prod.fecha_inicio}
                            required={true}
                            onChange={e=>{
                                    prod.fecha_inicio=e.target["value"];
                                    setFecha_inicio_rutas(e.target["value"]);
                                    UpdateFechaInicio(e);
                            }}
                            style={{width:"80%", border:"0px"}}
                        />
                    </IonCol>
                    <IonCol size="12" size-Xs="10" sizeMd="10" sizeLg="2" sizeXl="2" style={{textAlign:"center"}}>
                        <InputText
                            type="date"
                            value={prod.fecha_fin }
                            required={true}
                            onChange={e=>{
                                    prod.fecha_fin=e.target["value"];
                                    setFecha_fin_rutas(e.target["value"]);
                                    UpdateFechaFin(e);
                            }}

                            style={{width:"80%", border:"0px"}}
                        />
                    </IonCol>
                    <IonCol size="12" size-Xs="10" sizeMd="10" sizeLg="1" sizeXl="1" style={{textAlign:"center"}}>
                        <InputText
                        type="number" id="Descuentor" name="Descuentor" min="0" max="100"
                            //Se envía el valor al Excel
                            onChange={
                                e=>{
                                    prod.descuento=e.target["value"];
                                    setDescuento(e.target["value"]);
                                    UpdateDescuento(e);
                                }}
                            required={true} // <-Como es descuento de porcentaje, coloqué un min de 0 y un max de 100. Esta función de prod.descuento es lo que intenté ya que es lo que pone las fechas de acuerdo a la modificación de fecha inicio y fecha fin
                        
                        style={{width: "80%", border:"0px"}}
                        >
                        </InputText>
                    </IonCol>
                    <IonCol size="12" size-Xs="10" sizeMd="10" sizeLg="2" sizeXl="2" style={{textAlign:"center"}}>
                        <InputTextarea
                            rows={4} 
                            style={{width:"100%",border:"0px",color:"black", resize: "none"}}
                            defaultValue={prod.descripcion}
                        /> 
                    </IonCol>
```

El arreglo para hacer el Excel es el siguiente:

```
const AddDataToExcel =()=>{
        for (let index = 0; index < element.rutas.length; index++) {
            const elementr = element.rutas[index];
            dataEXcel.push({
                zona:element.etiqueta,
                tipo:"Ruta",
                producto:elementr.nombre,
                cantidad:elementr.cantidad,
                fecha_inicio:elementr.fecha_inicio,
                fecha_fin:elementr.fecha_fin,
                descripcion:elementr.descripcion,
                precio:0,
                descuento:elementr.descuento
            });
            
        }
    }


    for (let index = 0; index < productsRutas.length; index++) {
        const element = productsRutas[index];
        dataEXcel.push({
            zona:"",
            tipo:"Ruta",
            producto:element.nombre,
            cantidad:element.cantidad,
            fecha_inicio:element.fecha_inicio,
            fecha_fin:element.fecha_fin,
            descripcion:element.descripcion,
            precio:0,
            desuento: element.descuento
        });
    }
}
```

Muchas gracias de antemano y espero haber sido clara con el problema ya que la aplicación es enorme y procuré no poner tanto código. Si falta algo, lo puedo añadir sin problemas.

**EDIT:** Añado la función que uso en el Excel:

```
const exportExcel = async () => {
    let valuesToExport = dataEXcel;
    let wb= new Excel.Workbook();
    let ws = wb.addWorksheet('Pauta');

    //Línea para iniciar los encabezados a partir de la fila 5
    ws.getRow(5).values=['Zona', 'Tipo', 'Producto', 'Cantidad', 'Inicio', 'Fin', 'Descripción', 'Precio', 'Descuento', 'Total'];

    ws.columns=[
        {key: 'zona', width: 15},
        {key: 'tipo', width: 7},
        {key: 'producto', width: 13},
        {key: 'cantidad', width: 15},
        {key: 'fecha_inicio', width: 11},
        {key: 'fecha_fin', width: 11},
        {key: 'descripcion', width: 50},
        {key: 'precio', width: 14},
        {key: 'descuento', width: 17},
        {key: 'total', width: 15}
    ];
   
    for(let i=0; i<valuesToExport.length; i++)
    {
        const rowValues=[];

        const rowIndex=i +6;

        rowValues[1]=(valuesToExport[i]['zona']);
        rowValues[2]=(valuesToExport[i]['tipo']);
        rowValues[3]=(valuesToExport[i]['producto']);
        rowValues[4]=(valuesToExport[i]['cantidad']);
        rowValues[5]=(valuesToExport[i]['fecha_inicio']);
        rowValues[6]=(valuesToExport[i]['fecha_fin']);
        rowValues[7]=(valuesToExport[i]['descripcion']);
        rowValues[8]=(valuesToExport[i]['precio']);
        rowValues[9]=(valuesToExport[i]['descuento']); //<-Aquí debería grabarse
        //Columna calculada
        rowValues[10]= {
            formula: `=H${rowIndex}-(I${rowIndex}*H${rowIndex})`
          }  

        ws.addRow(rowValues);
    }

    //Formato de porcentaje a columna de descuentos
    ws.getColumn(9).numFmt = '0%';
    ws.getColumn(9).alignment={horizontal: 'center'};


    const buffer = await wb.xlsx.writeBuffer(); 
    const fileType = 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet;charset=UTF-8';
    let EXCEL_EXTENSION = '.xlsx';
    const blob= new Blob([buffer], {type: fileType});
    saveAs(blob, 'Pautas'+'_Export_'+ new Date().getTime()+EXCEL_EXTENSION);
}
```

Comment: Si los otros `<input>` te funcionan correctamente, por qué este otro `<input>` para el descuento no te funcionaría?

Comment: Porque estos input vienen de un array que se va generando cuando se agrega al carrito de compras. Algunos input se pueden modificar y otros no. El problema es que este es dado por el usuario y no se hace el "push" al arreglo. que uso para exportar al Excel

Comment: Y no puedes simplemente enviar ambos arreglos por parámetros al momento que el usuario da click o interactua con la descarga del Excel?

Comment: ¿Me podrías explicar más a fondo eso? Lo agradecería mucho.

Comment: Imagino que el usuario debe dar click en algun botón para realizar la exportación no? Entonces, podrías crear una función (si no la has creado aun), donde reciba como parámetro el arreglo de los inputs y el arreglo que trae los datos de descuento para incluirlos en al momento de crear el archivo Excel.. no sé si me explique bien

Comment: Creo que sí entendí. Voy a añadir mi función de exportación para que veas cómo recibo el arreglo.

Comment: La variable que guarda los descuentos se encuentra en ese mismo componente?

Comment: En valuesToExport tengo esto:
const AddDataToExcel =()=>{
        for (let index = 0; index < productsRutas.length; index++) {
            const element = productsRutas[index];
            dataEXcel.push({
                tipo:"Ruta",
                producto:element.nombre,
                cantidad:element.cantidad,
                fecha_inicio:element.fecha_inicio,
                fecha_fin:element.fecha_fin,
                descripcion:element.descripcion,
                precio:element.precioventa,
                desuento: element.descuento
            });
        }
    }

Comment: Por qué no utilizas simple javascript o jquery para obtener los valores de los inputs? Al momento de crearlos les asignas un id por producto y luego accedes a ellos dinámicamente.

Comment: No uso jquery, es en react, nodejs y typescript.